Combining Excel FILTER() and SUM() Functions
As efficiently as possible, I am wanting to take a tabular dataset in Excel where there are (purposefully) duplicate identifiers to records and consolidate this to a unique/summed dataset (very common in the type of work that I do).
I can of course do this with SUMIFS() and script a VBA-based solution, but I would really like to accomplish this with Excel's dynamic array functions (calculates in real time and no need for macro-enabled workbooks).
Attached is a visual:

Less evident here is that I used UNIQUE() in cell H4 (thus the reference to H4# in formula as shown in cell J4).  In the LET() statement, I am defining the source data as the values, and the identifiers as the color/type, which I then concatenate into a single string that I call 'srcKey'.
The unique combinations of these are then in the array H4#, which I capture as 'fltrKey'.  My desired output would be to retain the column breakout (hence the BYCOL() function), but sum the rows where the fltrKey is found within the srcKey.  This did not produce the correct results so I changed from fltrKey to direct cell references of H4 and I4 respectively (just as a test).
This gets me the right summed values for blue birds, but I want a dynamic formula that would have done this for each combination in my fltrKey.
It may be that my method here (using the FILTER() with ISNUMBER() and SEARCH() is not the appropriate approach).  I can get the intended results if just doing 1 column of the source values at a time, but that's not ideal/preferred.  I'm almost confident Excel can handle this, I just need help getting the methodology right.

Why do you think that using SUMIFS would require VBA? I don't see that.

I was unclear.  I can accomplish with SUMIFS() or VBA-based solution (not using both in combination).

One way is to use MAKEARRAY:
=LET(
    clr,B4:B10,
    typ,C4:C10,
    unq,H4#,
    val,D4:F10,
    MAKEARRAY(ROWS(unq),COLUMNS(val),LAMBDA(z,y,SUMIFS(INDEX(val,0,y),clr,INDEX(TAKE(unq,,1),z),typ,INDEX(TAKE(unq,,-1),z)))))


One note:
Once GROUPBY is widely available it can be used here:
=GROUPBY(B3:C10,D3:F10,SUM,3,0)



Nice addition on the GROUPBY.

'SUMIF' by Columns

To get the whole thing, including the headers and row labels, you could try the following:

=LET(data,B3:F13,u_cols,2,u_sort_cols,{2;1},
     h,TAKE(data,1),
     d,DROP(data,1),
     du,SORT(UNIQUE(TAKE(d,,u_cols)),u_sort_cols),
     sv,DROP(d,,u_cols),
     dv,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(du),COLUMNS(sv),LAMBDA(r,c,
         SUM(FILTER(INDEX(sv,,c),(INDEX(d,,1)=INDEX(du,r,1))
             *(INDEX(d,,2)=INDEX(du,r,2)))))),
     r,VSTACK(h,HSTACK(du,dv)),
     r)


Replace the last r with any other variable to see what it returns.



Just for fun, working with SUMIFS' range only requirement;
=LAMBDA(srcVal1, srcVal2, srcVal3, srcColors, srcTypes, header,
    LET(
        sum_, LAMBDA(srcVal,
            SUMIFS(srcVal, srcColors, srcColors, srcTypes, srcTypes)
        ),
        VSTACK(
            header,
            UNIQUE(
                HSTACK(
                    srcColors,
                    srcTypes,
                    sum_(srcVal1),
                    sum_(srcVal2),
                    sum_(srcVal3)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)(D4:D10, E4:E10, F4:F10, B4:B10, C4:C10, B3:F3)



Using REDUCE:
=LAMBDA(srcVals, srcColors, srcTypes, header,
    LET(
        sum_, LAMBDA(acc, srcValCol,
            HSTACK(
                acc,
                SUMIFS(
                    INDEX(srcVals, , srcValCol),
                    srcColors, srcColors,
                    srcTypes, srcTypes
                )
            )
        ),
        sums, REDUCE(
            HSTACK(srcColors, srcTypes),
            SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(srcVals)),
            sum_
        ),
        VSTACK(header, UNIQUE(sums))
    )
)(D4:F10, B4:B10, C4:C10, B3:F3)

